# Numerically decreasing iterator

Tags: rust, iterator

I need an open-ended decreasing integer iterator in Rust. `(..=n).rev()` does not work. The closest I've found is `std::iter::successors(Some(n), |n| Some(n - 1))`, which seems needlessly convoluted.

Is there a clearer way to express this notion of a numerically decreasing iterator?

Comment: I suppose another way is `(0..).map(|i| n - i)`. Still not very clear and an extra subtract every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly open-ended, but you could use the minimum value for whatever integer type you're targeting:

```
(i64::MIN..=n).rev()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify your starting bound on a range. That is write `(0..n).rev()`, or whatever should be your lowest number. And if you like to reinvent the wheel you can always write your own iterator.

Comment: Then this would not be an *open-ended* iterator, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by open-eneded? When should the iteration stop?

Comment: @Ana There is no open-ended integer. You could specify `i64::MIN` as the starting point to take the full negative range.

Comment: @GManNickG Yes, I suppose you're right. Technically no open-ended integer in Rust. Min for the type.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to subtract the numbers 0, 1, ... from `n`:

```
(0..).map(|i| n - i)
```

This avoids mentioning `<int type>::MIN`, which kind of distracts from the intention. Of course this implementation can only count down to the minimum of the type as well, so you may just as well make that limitation explicit.